# Why "iterative" function $f(x)=k\sqrt[2]{x}$ converge to $k^2$

Tags: functions, soft-question

Disclaimer: I do not have a maths degree, but is just one curious bloke. Be nice.

What do you call a function whose answer is repeatedly inserted into the function? For example $f(x) = 2x^2 +2$. If $x=1$, then $f(x)=4$. Plug in $x=4$, thus $f(x)=34$, and then plug $x=34$ to $f(x)$, and so on.

Given that property of the function, can anyone explain why this function:

$$f(x)=k\sqrt[2]{x}$$

converges to $k^2$ if you perform several iterations of the process? In general, what is this process/property called? Are there any other quirks like this? Thanks.

Comment: You can start from [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_iteration)

Comment: $k^2$ is called a fixed point. I assume you can see that $f(k^2) = k^2$. But that doesn't imply that the iteration will necessarily converge to $k^2$. Some fixed points are attractive, but some are repelling. Eg, if we invert your function, $F(y) = y^2 / k^2$, then $k^2$ is a repelling fixed point of $F$.

Answer (score 1):

Fix $x$. Take $a_n=k\sqrt{k\sqrt{k\sqrt{...k\sqrt{x}}}} \quad (n\quad times)$ therefore we have $a_{n+1}=k\sqrt{a_n}$. For $k=0$ it's trivial so take $k\ne0$. Now define $b_n=\frac{a_n}{k^2}$ then:$$b_{n+1}=\frac{|k|}{k}\sqrt{b_n}$$ for $b_n$'s being real we must have $k>0$ so $b_{n+1}=\sqrt{b_n}$. If $b_1\ge 1$ so is $b_2$, $b_3$ and ... and the sequence is monotonically decreasing because $1\le b_{n+1}=\sqrt{b_n}\le b_n$ and since it has $1$ as a lower bound it's convergent ,say to $l\ge 1$. Therefore $l=\sqrt l$ which deduces $l=0$ or $l=1$ where $l=1$ is valid. Investigating $b_n$'s when $b_1\le 1$ is likewise. So $lim_{n\to\infty}b_n=1$ which implies $lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=k^2$